# Total in a mysql pivot query

Tags: mysql, pivot

I've this pivot query:

```
SELECT `fonte`, 

MAX(IF(month= '1', sell, NULL)) AS Gen,  
MAX(IF(month= '2', sell, NULL)) AS Feb, 
MAX(IF(month= '3', sell, NULL)) AS Mar, 
MAX(IF(month= '4', sell, NULL)) AS Apr, 
MAX(IF(month= '5', sell, NULL)) AS Mag, 
MAX(IF(month= '6', sell, NULL)) AS Giu, 
MAX(IF(month= '7', sell, NULL)) AS Lug, 
MAX(IF(month= '8', sell, NULL)) AS Ago, 
MAX(IF(month= '9', sell, NULL)) AS Sett, 
MAX(IF(month= '10', sell, NULL)) AS Ott, 
MAX(IF(month= '11', sell, NULL)) AS Nov, 
MAX(IF(month= '12', sell, NULL)) AS Dic,

FROM `pdl_dati` group by fonte
```

How can I insert the "total" for month='1' and month='2' and month='3' and month='4' and month='5' and month='6' and month='7' and month='8' and month='9' and month='10' and month='11' and month='12'?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want a final row that has a total for each month you can use `GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP`:

```
SELECT `fonte`, 
  MAX(IF(month= '1', sell, NULL)) AS Gen,   -- do you want this to be sum?
  MAX(IF(month= '2', sell, NULL)) AS Feb, 
  MAX(IF(month= '3', sell, NULL)) AS Mar, 
  MAX(IF(month= '4', sell, NULL)) AS Apr, 
  MAX(IF(month= '5', sell, NULL)) AS Mag, 
  MAX(IF(month= '6', sell, NULL)) AS Giu, 
  MAX(IF(month= '7', sell, NULL)) AS Lug, 
  MAX(IF(month= '8', sell, NULL)) AS Ago, 
  MAX(IF(month= '9', sell, NULL)) AS Sett, 
  MAX(IF(month= '10', sell, NULL)) AS Ott, 
  MAX(IF(month= '11', sell, NULL)) AS Nov, 
  MAX(IF(month= '12', sell, NULL)) AS Dic
FROM `pdl_dati` 
group by fonte with ROLLUP;
```

As a side note, if you are attempting to get the total for each `fonte` by month, I would think you would want to use `sum` instead of `max`. See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4bacc/2)